# Is it possible to pipe source code to GHC through standard input?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I mean something like this:

```
echo 'main = print 1' | ghc > executable
```

To which GHC replies: `ghc: no input files`

Am I missing something? Is this possible somehow?

Comment: This works with runghc, but that won't create an executable.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? To run some piece of Haskell code, or to actually compile it into a stand-alone binary? Depending on what you're after, there may be easier ways than manually invoking the GHC binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though this isn't possible with normal [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution), zsh provides a [special kind of process substitution-like behavior](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html#IDX49) that allows the "file" to act like more of a real file than traditional process substitution does (by creating an actual temporary file):

```
% ghc -o Main -x hs =( echo 'main = print 1' )
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/zshjlS99o, /tmp/zshjlS99o.o )
Linking Main ...
% ./Main
1
%
```

The `-x hs` option tells `ghc` to act as though the file name given ends in `.hs`.

Overall, this is essentially a shortcut around manually creating and deleting a temporary file.

I'm not sure if there are other shells that support this kind of thing. I don't think bash does, at least.

Comment: I am marking this as a solution for now because this is the most concise way to achieve what I was looking for. If someone posts a similarly-succinct  version that works outside zsh (e.g. I've tried `ghc -o executable $(echo "main = print 1" | mktemp --suffix=.hs)` without success yet) or GHC implements support internally, then I will change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, the answer is no. My attempts:

1. `$ echo 'main = print 1' | ghc 
   ghc: no input files`
2. `$ echo 'main = print 1' | ghc -
   ghc: unrecognised flag: -`
3. `$ echo 'main = print 1' | ghc /dev/stdin
   target ‘/dev/stdin’ is not a module name or a source file`
4. `$ ln -s /dev/stdin stdin.hs; echo 'main = print 1' | ghc stdin.hs
   stdin.hs: hFileSize: inappropriate type (not a regular file)`

The problems: ghc uses suffixes like `.hs`, `.lhs`, or `.o` to decide what to do with a file (this is why #3 fails). Even if you hack around that (#4), ghc really wants to `stat()` the file to get its size, which fails on pipes.

Comment: simpler #4: `echo 'main = print 1' | ghc -x hs /dev/stdin`

Answer (score 2):

Typically ghc is used as a compiler and you run it on files (on which ghc can seek and infer types from endings etc) and specify output files as flags.

You can, however, of course, use

```
filename=$(mktemp --suffix=.hs)
echo "main = print 1" >> $filename
ghc -o executable $filename
```

Answer (score 2):

This might not be what you want, but as melpomene already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350897/is-it-possible-to-pipe-source-code-to-ghc-through-standard-input#comment50685069_31350897), runghc can do that. I think it deserves its own answer:

```sh
runghc <<< 'main = print 123'
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6g0Lz0jWcHGxkZBPTcxM0/BVqGgKDOvRMHQyFj9/38A)